# Why is the chi-square test used to determine conformity to Benford's Law?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

As far as I know, the chi-square test only applies to normal distributions, does it not? So it is only statistically significant for normal distributions.

But data sets that are Benford (i.e. seem to follow Benford's Law) are obviously not normally distributed. So why do so many people use the chi-square test to determine the degree of conformity to Benford's Law?

Comment: No, you can use chi squared to test goodness of fit to any distribution.

Comment: The chi-square test can also be used to verify equal-distributions, for example, whether a dice is fair.

Comment: See the Wikipedia story about using the chi-square statistic for count data:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Pearson's_chi-squared_test